# How to force margins to be ready from js before document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using an effect a website I have built to detect and move the website from on document ready as well as when the browser window is resized.  There is an effect I must address that I did not consider. When the page loads it reads css from the css file and once document is ready it reads from dynamic value provided from js. I was hoping someone can give some insight on how I can read the js value before the css value.

Thank you in advance,

DT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this example http://jsfiddle.net/efortis/kUfdE/

First, hide it by default in the CSS with `display:none`

```
.orangeBox{
  background: orange;
  display: none;
}
```

Then display it with javascript, equivalent to `.css('display', 'block')` to show the `display:none` element

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.orangeBox').delay(1500).fadeIn('slow');
});
```